# How to set images in tabhost using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabhost

I have navigation drawer from [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)..now when i run the application first item of drawer is appearing

In my fragment i added Tabhost,in my Tabhost i am able to set text,but i want to put images instead of text

following is my code can any one help

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private SearchView searchView;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.my_parent_fragment);

        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);


       // tabHost.newTabSpec("All").setIndicator(null,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(R.id.tab_template_two_tabs_all);

       // tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("The Tab", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setContent(new Intent(getActivity(), DiscoverFragment.class)));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First"), DiscoverFragment.class, arg1);

        //  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("TAb1").setIndicator("Tab1"),FragmentA.class,arg1);

        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sec").setIndicator("Sec"), ShopFragment.class, arg2);

        Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third"), Thirdtab.class, arg3);

        Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag4", 4);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Four").setIndicator("Four"), FourthTabs.class, arg4);
        return tabHost;


    }


}
```

xml

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("name",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.port))
                    .setContent(intent);
```

Try it.

Comment: accepted and votee up it works...but any idea how to set height widht of image?

Comment: i edited your answer it will helpful to others with fragments

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Activity by using TabActivity. **TabActivity is deprecated.**

```html
TabHost tabHost;

tabHost = getTabHost();
  setTabs();

String arrTabId[] = new String[] { "tab 1", "tab 2",
   "tab 3", "tab 4", "tab 5" };


private void setTabs() {
  addTab(arrTabId[0], R.drawable.first_tab, Activity_List.class);
  addTab(arrTabId[1], R.drawable.second_tab, PedidosActivity.class);
  addTab(arrTabId[2], R.drawable.pedidos, ApplicationActivity.class);
  addTab(arrTabId[3], R.drawable.third_tab, ChatActivity.class);
  addTab(arrTabId[4], R.drawable.fourth_tab, SettingActivity.class);
 }



private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
  TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(labelId);

  View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
    R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
  ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

  icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
  spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
  spec.setContent(intent);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);
 }
```

In design library you will also get Sliding tabs. You customize that also by inflating a layout.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your tabhost to

```
   tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sec").
    setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.string.tab1, R.drawable.image1)), ShopFragment.class, arg2);

     /** For both Image and text view 
         *   Remove text if you don't need
         */
      private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.indicatorImageView);
                        iv.setImageResource(icon);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.indicatorText);
                        tv.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
                        tv.setText(title);
                        return view;
                    }
```

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/indicatorImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/indicatorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```